# angular 2 websql typings

Tags: angular, web-sql, typescript-typings

I am writing an app in electron using angular 4. I need a database and want to use websql but I cannot find a way to import websql typings.

I added @types/websql. In my IDE, there is no compil error when i do :

```
const db: Database = window.openDatabase('foo', '1.0', 'foo', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

but `ng serve` gives me :

```
Property 'openDatabase' does not exist on type 'Window'
```

I do not have any import specific to `@types/websql`. As it is not a module, I don't know how to import it.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can import this ?

Comment: It seems when I try to compile with tsc, it works. So I guess the issue here is with ng-cli...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

ng-cli generate a tsconfig.app.json with a property `types` set to [].
If I understand tsc doc correctly, it prevents the compiler to use the `typeRoots` property.

By simply removing this property, my code compile.

Answer (score 1):

As in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html:

> all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation ...
>
> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.
>
> If types is specified, only packages under types will be included.

If i put the type in ts.config.app like this configuration:

```
"types": [
  "websql"
]
```

it will only include the *node_modules/@types/websql* ignoring others that may have been installed.

Comment: You should consider providing an explanation with your answer. For more information, please read : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)