# Angular 4 / WebSql : can not find name 'openDatabase'?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-sql

I'm using websql in angular 4 project , but Typescript can't find some of the types:

```
 this.db = openDatabase('tes', '1.0', 'test', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

But some how is accepting the transaction :

```
this.db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql(query);
  tx.executeSql(qr);
})
```

I'm always getting :

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'openDatabase'

Comment: what is OpenDatabase?

Comment: it's the name of the method, in js it is by default exsist , i tried to follow this tuto in websql : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/02/using-websql-instead-local-storage-web-app/

Comment: I found the solution in this and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385151/angular-2-websql-typings